# Valid file path throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsoup, fileutils

I have a list of images I'm trying to download in Java. This works:

```
     for (String i : link_array) {

         File image = new File(outputFolderImages, image_id+".gif");
         if (!image.exists()) {
             System.out.println("Downloading: "+i+" to file "+image);
             FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(i), image, 10000, 10000);
         }
     }
```

However, a different part of the program I'm writing necessitates using the path already in the image link. So if if this is [the link](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/05785.gif), I would want to save the image as `05785.gif`. So I tried this:

```
    for (String i : link_array) {
        String x = i.replace("http://www.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/","");
        File image = new File(outputFolderImages, x);

        if (!image.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Downloading: "+i+" to file "+image);
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(i), image, 10000, 10000);
        }
    }
```

But this throws the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ian\Homestuck\images\05785.gif
 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Even though this is a valid file path; I've saved hundreds of other images uses the first code bit above. How can I fix this?

Comment: is the parent directory exist ?

Comment: Yes, I used the first block of code to save several thousand other images there.

Comment: Are these two blocks from the same method? Could you possibly have code that alters `outputFolderImages`?

Comment: Yes, they are from the same method, and no, `outputFolderImages` remains the same.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, as I currently don't have access to a Windows system, so I cannot replicate your issue, but it seems to me like you might be having issues with using the '\' as a files separator.  Specifically, you'll have a big issue with the '\' separator when put next to a '0', as that is the way to indicate 'null' in java, which can cause problems for Strings.

Comment: It was trailing newlines; thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with trailing newlines.